# Workaround for currentStyle in Safari

Tags: html, safari, cross-browser

Accessing an html element's current style using Element.currentStyle only exists in IE.  Is there any easy workaround for Safari or other non-IE browsers?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by checking the current style?

Comment: I am making some code work in Safari and in this case I'm trying to set the width of an element to that of its parent.  In this case I can set the width to 'inherit' and won't even need the answer I provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Safari I can get the current style using getComputedStyle like this:

```
window.getComputedStyle(element, null).width;
```

I found this [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html).